# Http Authorization Header

Tags: c#, curl, http-headers

I would like to get the response of a json api provided by some website this is their cURL Request

```
curl --include --header "X-Access-Token: XXXXX" "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/latest?"
```

trying to get the content using

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Access-Token", "XXXXX");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(contents);
}
```

but still getting

```
{"success":false,"data":null,"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

Comment: Are you using the correct access token? That code is working for me.

Comment: my bad i'm not using the correct token, how foolish of me

Comment: Are you sure that the want to include that token in your code, rather than elide it so it isn't visible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using token? in your code it looks like a marker.
Here is my output:

```
@e:~$ curl --include --header "X-Access-Token: d273e9325fXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/latest?currency=rub&period_type=year&page=1&limit=30&show_to_affiliates=true&sorting=price&trip_class=0"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.4
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 13:53:52 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 7083
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Status: 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

{"success": true, "data":
```

Comment: my bad i'm not using the correct token, how foolish of me